# JSON Serialize/Deserialize Varbinary DataColumn becomes String not Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, json

**Overall Description**

I have a web service that:

- Retrieves a dataset from our
     database
- Uses `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to serialize the
     object and returns that data to a user's local application as a string

then my client's local application:

- Uses `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>()` to convert the object back into a System.Data.DataSet

**My problem**

I have a Data Column that holds Varbinary data (Byte[]). This serialize/deserialize process ends up causing that column data type to be a String (I'm guessing base64).

Is there a way that when I deserialize the JSON object that it treats this column as a varbinary?

EDIT: In response to comments

My issue is that I generate a CREATE TABLE scripts based on the columns of my DataSet. When I iterate through the columns I need to specify what datatype each column will be in this new table I generate with SQL. For the columns that should be varbinary my DataColumn data type is String and is indistinguishable from actual string columns like 'Username'

Comment: The only way JSON represents a byte[] is as a base64 encoded string. It should still deserialize into a byte[]. What is your issue?

Comment: @eulerfx the "issue" is that there is NO DIFFERENCE in the serialised data when how JSON serialises string and binary data. When JSON deserialises either String or Binary column data, a String results; I tried it. It wasn't surprising when I viewed the serialised data <{"MyDT":[{"MyDataColStr":"MyValue","MyDataColBin":"QTJj"}]}> I am surprised that, as someone who has such high 'reputation', you speak with such authority on things outside your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

As @eulerfx mentioned you can leave it that way. But if you absolutely need an array use a int[] instead of byte[]. I needed to present the array of numbers as an array of numbers in other contexts (UI) and this worked for me.